# Wants to send my bitcoin to another wallet

Tags: private-key, qrcode

[image]
I’m having issues trying to send my bitcoin to another wallet...it been asking me to confirm a whr code which I don’t really understand cos I have enough money on my wallet

Answer (score 1):

The address you have is a watch-only address, meaning you can only watch it, but not send it without the private key. The private key is something you HAVE TO have in order to send it.

It's 32 bytes in size and starts with a `5`